# Creating DeepRacer Model with default configuration results in "Failed to create model" error

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am going through the `AWS DeepRacer: Driven by Reinforcement Learning` training located here:
https://www.aws.training/learningobject/wbc?id=32143 and am unable to successfully create a model.

When attempting to create a model in the DeepRacer console using the default configuration, I have not been able to successfully create a model using the default configuration.

I continually get and error saying `Failed to create model. Unable to create your model.` with no other information. There are no relevant logs generated in CloudWatch.

I have tried resetting my Account Resources and recreating them, but that has not changed the result.

Any insight into whats going on?

Comment: Does your model fail straight away?

Answer (score 1):

My model failed last night for the same reason, it trained for just over 1 hour then crashed.

I cloned the model and re-trained and the 3 hours worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you check your quota on ML.C4.2XL boxes. Some accounts have it set to zero and I don't think UI handles it too well. If that is the case, support are quite helpful with increasing it.

Answer (score -1):

I guess if you are running Deeprunner Instance using root user it will throw such error. Create an IAM user and allow admin rights. Hope it works